# How to integrate a $C^1$ function $f$ with respect to angle?

Tags: calculus, polar-coordinates

The only given condition is that $f$ is  a $C^1$ function defined on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

How can I find the value of $$\lim_{r \rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0 ^{2\pi}\frac{\cos \theta}{r} f(r\cos \theta, r\sin \theta)d\theta$$

I tried to interchange the coordinate into standard coordinate, but I think it is useless as so complicated.

Thank you if you give me any hints.

Comment: What sort of answer are you expecting?  Clearly one needs to know a lot about the function $f$, right?

Comment: Surely, its value depends on the function $f$, I want to get the answer of form, for example, $f(0,0)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the formula for directional derivatives we have
$$
\lim_{r \to 0} \frac{f(r\cos\theta, r\sin\theta)-f(0,0)}{r} = (\nabla f(0,0))\cdot (\cos\theta, \sin\theta) = f_x(0,0)\cos\theta + f_y(0,0)\sin\theta. 
$$
Thus
$$
\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} \cos\theta \Big( \frac{f(r\cos\theta, r\sin\theta)-f(0,0)}{r} +  \frac{f(0,0)}{r}\Big) d \theta 
$$
$$
=\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} \cos\theta \Big( \frac{f(r\cos\theta, r\sin\theta)-f(0,0)}{r} \Big) d \theta 
$$
$$
\to_{r \to 0} \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi}\cos\theta(f_x(0,0)\cos\theta + f_y(0,0)\sin\theta)d \theta  
$$
$$
=\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} f_x(0,0)(\cos\theta)^2 d \theta  = \frac{f_x(0,0)}{2}.
$$